# Jaspersoft - List consumindo espaço quando vazio

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jasper, jaspersoft-studio

Tenho um relatório que tem um group header e dentro dele existem dois lists.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fiz um tratamento via expressão para imprimir cada um dos lists apenas quando existir conteúdo para cada um deles, porém quando um deles não é exibido o relatório deixa um espaço em branco indevido.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de saber como tratar este espaço em branco. Tentei marcar as propriedades `isRemoveLineWhenBlank` e `isBlankWhenNull` porém não resolveu o problema.

Comment: Você pode tratar sua coleção no Java? Se sim, você pode remover a referência dessa linha sem conteúdo na aplicação em vez de delegar para o Jasper. Seria bom conhecer a estrutura do .jrxml desse relatório também.

Comment: Oi @ℛɑƒæĿ, consegui resolver de outra maneira. Separei cada list em um group header diferente e tratei a exibição direto na band. De qualquer forma agradeço o contato.

Comment: Beleza @Luís Felipe, que bom que conseguiu resolver e compartilhou a solução!